# Fazer conexão com o SQL com AppConfig

Tags: c#, sql-server

Como posso fazer uma conexão com o SQL com o connectionstring no AppConfig?

Eu fiz assim, mas queria que pudesse ser pelo AppConfig, como posso fazer?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=Banco;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Senha";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Conectado com sucesso");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao conectar");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `app.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MinhaConnString" connectionString="Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=Banco;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Senha" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Você consegue obter a string de conexão assim:

```
string connectionStr = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["MinhaConnString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
// ...
```

É necessário referenciar o assembly `System.Configuration.dll`

Comment: Eu fiz isto e meu programa fecha quando clico no botão

Comment: Este é o código padrão para esta operação, confirme que os nomes estão corretos e a string de conexão também. Em todo debugue o código e veja se lança alguma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Coloque o break-point e veja e qual momento o programa fecha

Comment: Consegui já, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No seu app.config coloque:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

E depois você consegue criar a conexão dessa forma:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: O seu também funcionou, obrigado.